# Kubernetes replication controller in CrashLoopBackOff state

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-health-check

I performed the following steps.

Created the replication controller with the following config file:

```
{
   "kind":"ReplicationController",
   "apiVersion":"v1",
   "metadata":{
      "name":"fsharp-service",
      "labels":{
         "app":"fsharp-service"
      }
   },
   "spec":{
      "replicas":1,
      "selector":{
         "app":"fsharp-service"
      },
      "template":{
         "metadata":{
            "labels":{
               "app":"fsharp-service"
            }
         },
         "spec":{
            "containers":[
               {
                  "name":"fsharp-service",
                  "image":"fsharp/fsharp:latest",
                  "ports":[
                     {
                        "name":"http-server",
                        "containerPort":3000
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Run the command:

```
kubectl create -f fsharp-controller.json
```

Here is the output:

```
$ kubectl get rc
CONTROLLER       CONTAINER(S)     IMAGE(S)                             SELECTOR             REPLICAS
cassandra        cassandra        gcr.io/google-samples/cassandra:v8   app=cassandra        3
fsharp-service   fsharp-service   fsharp/fsharp:latest                 app=fsharp-service   1
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                   READY     REASON    RESTARTS   AGE
cassandra              1/1       Running   0          28m
cassandra-ch1br        1/1       Running   0          28m
cassandra-xog49        1/1       Running   0          27m
fsharp-service-7lrq8   0/1       Error     2          31s
$ kubectl logs fsharp-service-7lrq8

F# Interactive for F# 4.0 (Open Source Edition)
Freely distributed under the Apache 2.0 Open Source License

For help type #help;;

$ kubectl get pods
NAME                   READY     REASON             RESTARTS   AGE
cassandra              1/1       Running            0          28m
cassandra-ch1br        1/1       Running            0          28m
cassandra-xog49        1/1       Running            0          28m
fsharp-service-7lrq8   0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   3          1m
$ kubectl describe po fsharp-service-7lrq8
W0417 15:52:36.288492   11461 request.go:302] field selector: v1 - events - involvedObject.name - fsharp-service-7lrq8: need to check if this is versioned correctly.
W0417 15:52:36.289196   11461 request.go:302] field selector: v1 - events - involvedObject.namespace - default: need to check if this is versioned correctly.
W0417 15:52:36.289204   11461 request.go:302] field selector: v1 - events - involvedObject.uid - d4dab099-04ee-11e6-b7f9-0a11c670939b: need to check if this is versioned correctly.
Name:               fsharp-service-7lrq8
Image(s):           fsharp/fsharp:latest
Node:               ip-172-20-0-228.us-west-2.compute.internal/172.20.0.228
Labels:             app=fsharp-service
Status:             Running
Replication Controllers:    fsharp-service (1/1 replicas created)
Containers:
  fsharp-service:
    Image:      fsharp/fsharp:latest
    State:      Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Ready:      False
    Restart Count:  3
Conditions:
  Type      Status
  Ready     False
Events:
  FirstSeen             LastSeen            Count   From                            SubobjectPath           Reason      Message
  Sun, 17 Apr 2016 15:50:50 -0700   Sun, 17 Apr 2016 15:50:50 -0700 1   {default-scheduler }                                    Scheduled   Successfully assigned fsharp-service-7lrq8 to ip-172-20-0-228.us-west-2.compute.internal
  Sun, 17 Apr 2016 15:50:51 -0700   Sun, 17 Apr 2016 15:50:51 -0700 1   {kubelet ip-172-20-0-228.us-west-2.compute.internal}    spec.containers{fsharp-service} Created     Created container with docker id d44c288ea67b
  Sun, 17 Apr 2016 15:50:51 -0700   Sun, 17 Apr 2016 15:50:51 -0700 1   {kubelet ip-172-20-0-228.us-west-2.compute.internal}    spec.containers{fsharp-service} Started     Started container with docker id d44c288ea67b
  Sun, 17 Apr 2016 15:50:55 -0700   Sun, 17 Apr 2016 15:50:55 -0700 1   {kubelet ip-172-20-0-228.us-west-2.compute.internal}    spec.containers{fsharp-service} Started     Started container with docker id 688a3ed122d2
  Sun, 17 Apr 2016 15:50:55 -0700   Sun, 17 Apr 2016 15:50:55 -0700 1   {kubelet ip-172-20-0-228.us-west-2.compute.internal}    spec.containers{fsharp-service} Created     Created container with docker id 688a3ed122d2
  Sun, 17 Apr 2016 15:50:58 -0700   Sun, 17 Apr 2016 15:50:58 -0700 1   {kubelet ip-172-20-0-228.us-west-2.compute.internal}                    FailedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "fsharp-service" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 10s restarting failed container=fsharp-service pod=fsharp-service-7lrq8_default(d4dab099-04ee-11e6-b7f9-0a11c670939b)"

  Sun, 17 Apr 2016 15:51:15 -0700   Sun, 17 Apr 2016 15:51:15 -0700 1   {kubelet ip-172-20-0-228.us-west-2.compute.internal}    spec.containers{fsharp-service} Started     Started container with docker id c2e348e1722d
  Sun, 17 Apr 2016 15:51:15 -0700   Sun, 17 Apr 2016 15:51:15 -0700 1   {kubelet ip-172-20-0-228.us-west-2.compute.internal}    spec.containers{fsharp-service} Created     Created container with docker id c2e348e1722d
  Sun, 17 Apr 2016 15:51:17 -0700   Sun, 17 Apr 2016 15:51:31 -0700 2   {kubelet ip-172-20-0-228.us-west-2.compute.internal}                    FailedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "fsharp-service" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 20s restarting failed container=fsharp-service pod=fsharp-service-7lrq8_default(d4dab099-04ee-11e6-b7f9-0a11c670939b)"

  Sun, 17 Apr 2016 15:50:50 -0700   Sun, 17 Apr 2016 15:51:44 -0700 4   {kubelet ip-172-20-0-228.us-west-2.compute.internal}    spec.containers{fsharp-service} Pulling     pulling image "fsharp/fsharp:latest"
  Sun, 17 Apr 2016 15:51:45 -0700   Sun, 17 Apr 2016 15:51:45 -0700 1   {kubelet ip-172-20-0-228.us-west-2.compute.internal}    spec.containers{fsharp-service} Created     Created container with docker id edaea97fb379
  Sun, 17 Apr 2016 15:50:51 -0700   Sun, 17 Apr 2016 15:51:45 -0700 4   {kubelet ip-172-20-0-228.us-west-2.compute.internal}    spec.containers{fsharp-service} Pulled      Successfully pulled image "fsharp/fsharp:latest"
  Sun, 17 Apr 2016 15:51:46 -0700   Sun, 17 Apr 2016 15:51:46 -0700 1   {kubelet ip-172-20-0-228.us-west-2.compute.internal}    spec.containers{fsharp-service} Started     Started container with docker id edaea97fb379
  Sun, 17 Apr 2016 15:50:58 -0700   Sun, 17 Apr 2016 15:52:27 -0700 7   {kubelet ip-172-20-0-228.us-west-2.compute.internal}    spec.containers{fsharp-service} BackOff     Back-off restarting failed docker container
  Sun, 17 Apr 2016 15:51:48 -0700   Sun, 17 Apr 2016 15:52:27 -0700 4   {kubelet ip-172-20-0-228.us-west-2.compute.internal}                    FailedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "fsharp-service" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 40s restarting failed container=fsharp-service pod=fsharp-service-7lrq8_default(d4dab099-04ee-11e6-b7f9-0a11c670939b)"
```

What is  wrong?

How can I find out the reason why the controller won't start correctly?

UPDATE.

I have tried to change the simple "fsharp/fsharp:latest" image to another image where there would be a service listening to a port, this is how I want to use the container.

The image is called "username/someservice:mytag" and has a service listening to the port 3000.

I run the service as:

```
mono Service.exe
```

When I look at the logs I see this:

```
$ kubectl logs -p fsharp-service-wjmpv
Running on http://127.0.0.1:3000
Press enter to exit
```

So the container is in the same state even though the process shouldn't exit:

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                   READY     REASON             RESTARTS   AGE
fsharp-service-wjmpv   0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   9          25m
```

I also tried to run the container from my image with the -i flag, to make the container not exit, but kubectl doesn't seem to recognize -i flag :\

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added the following line to my F# service (Unix specific code) to make sure process doesn't exit:

```
let signals = [| new UnixSignal (Signum.SIGINT); 
                 new UnixSignal (Signum.SIGTERM); 
                 new UnixSignal (Signum.SIGQUIT)
              |]

let which = UnixSignal.WaitAny (signals, -1);
```

After that my replication controller is running normally.

Answer (score 3):

You are launching a container that immediately exits. The kubelet notices, restarts it, and then it exits again. After this happens a few times, the kubelet slows down the rate at which it tries to launch the container (this is the CrashLoopBackOff state).

The [fsharp documentation](https://hub.docker.com/r/fsharp/fsharp/) says to run the container with the `-i` flag, which gives an interactive prompt. If you just do

```
docker run fsharp/fsharp:latest
```

you'll notice that the container exits immediately and dumps you back into your local shell. This is the way in which you are trying to invoke the container in your cluster, and it is likewise exiting immediately.

Comment: I have updated my question. Added the results of my attempt with another image (image where I run the service that listens to port 3000, based on fsharp image)

Answer (score 3):

I would use `kubectl logs` to try to find out what has happened to your container, like so:

```
kubectl logs -p fsharp-service-7lrq8
```

The `-p` flag lets you get logs for the previous startup which is necessary in this case since the container is crashing.

More information: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_logs/

Comment: Thanks, but the logs are empty, just an F# interactive prompt message

Comment: What you are trying to achieve? Judging from the port that you've added you intend to run some kind of web service but to me no such web service seems to exist in the container since you are just executing the vanilla F# container.

Comment: I know nothing about F# though so please forgive my ignorance. According to @RobertBaily it seems like all you're image does is to start an interactive prompt and then exit unless started in interactive mode. Why would you want to start a container that does nothing within Kubernetes? If you really do I would suggest starting your container with an infinite sleep. Eg. Add something similar to this to your container definition: `command: [ "bin/bash", "-c", "sleep", "10000d" ]`

Comment: You're right, this is my hello world trial attempt, so I just tried to run any container. In real life I will have a customized image based on fsharp image with a web service, to where I'd have to pass the necessary parameters. This particular container exits, but I wanted to check if it works. I will try it in the interactive way and then with my customized image

Comment: @TobiasGustafsson request you to promote you comment to an answer. This one helped solve my issue.